# SQL command is wrong or doesn't work

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

this is my SQL Command and i don't know whats wrong with it or if something is wrong ?

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Lager SET Anzahl = '" & Anzahl +  
                   nudAnzahlEditieren.Value & "' WHERE Gegenstand = '" &  
                   lvLagersystem.SelectedItem(1).ToString & "'"
```

Comment: What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: I got it da.UpdateCommand = con.CreateCommand
            da.UpdateCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Lager SET Anzahl = '" & Anzahl + nudAnzahlEditieren.Value & "' WHERE Gegenstand = '" & lvLagersystem.SelectedItem(1).ToString & "'"
            da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: Thnks for your help

Comment: Learn to use parameters!  Don't munge query strings with such values.

Comment: Learn how to use parameterized queries. I bet that all your problems will go away. And remember that the + operator is not the correct one to use when you want to concatenate strings

Comment: Please edit your question with your extra code. No one can make sense of it in the comments. Then explain why you think it's wrong. Do you get an error? Post it!

Comment: [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the & lvLagersystem.SelectedItem(1).ToString & is inside the " " statement , so its looking forsomthing that called "& lvLagersystem.SelectedItem(1).ToString &"
and not what is suppose to represent.

I would try first inserting & lvLagersystem.SelectedItem(1).ToString & to a string and then sending the full string,
unfortunately i dont know VB to write a proper example for you.

Comment: No Problem, 
Glad to hear